# The data in the inputfile for sqlplus

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sqlplus

with `sqlplus usr/password@database_name @inputfile` i build a connection to the database and pass it over the inputfile, to read the sql-statements.

The inputfile looks like this:

```
update table1
set column1 = '1'
where column1 != '0';
commit
```

if I execute this statements manually on the sqlplus command line it works like I want, column1 is set to 1. But giving the statements over the inputfile doenst work for me.

What am I missing here? I really dont get it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem. Do you have an error or it does not do anything?

Comment: Is there any error or is it just not getting updated?

Comment: what exactly do you write on the command line? Share the exact command and parameters please. Anything may be wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a semi colon after commit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `terminal character`. As already suggested, use `semicolon` to terminate that `line`.

```
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

If you have `multiline` scenario, then when you enter a SQL statement, `SQL*Plus` fills something what it calls a `buffer`. The **`/`** now executes what is currently in the buffer.

Let's see what happens to `commit` statement i it is not terminated :

```
SQL> commit
  2
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> /

Commit complete.

SQL
```